# Why is Craft hanging every time I try to save an entry?

Tags: error

I just upgraded to the latest version of Craft.  I can login and create a new entry, but then it hangs when I try to save it.  I can't even stop and go back to the entries panel.  I have to exit out of Safari or Chrome and go back in.  Sometimes it has saved the entry and other times it has not.  There are no error or pop of notification of any sort.

And by hang - I mean seizes up and freezes for about 5-10 minutes ...and sometimes creates a duplicate entry.

Comment: i'd have a look at the logs, then  email P&T from the dashboard and explain in detail what you're doing. Their support is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be Intego anti-virus software on my one machine.  The problem does not appear on computers that lack Intego.